# Java run from command line: class path include folders and subfolders

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

I am asking a basic Java question. I need to run my Java program on a server so I have to do it from the cmmand line. The problem is that I am getting a

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: utils/Compare
```

I am running

```
java -cp bin:../../lib/*:../../bin/* Test
```

Everything in bin and ../../lib/* is recognized so it is OK but not the classes in ../../bin/ which has multiple subfolders. It is complaining about a class in a subfolder. In fact if I specifically include that subfolder in the classpath

```
java -cp bin:../../lib/*:../../bin/utils/* Test
```

It also does not work. All the classes are there and the paths are correct. I compile it with ant and the compilation goes OK.

Ubdate:

/Evaluation: /bin

/../../Evaluation: /bin/utils, bin/documents, and so on

The class Compare.class for which it is complaining is right inside utils

Thank you in advance.

Altober

SOLUTION:

I missed the last colon it should be

```
java -cp bin:../../lib/*:../../bin/: Test
```

Comment: I think the folder containing class files should be specified as `../../bin/utils/` (no wildcard).

Comment: thanks but it is still not working

Comment: Check the package declaration, and make sure the root is on the classpath. If your class is `com.foo.bar.MyClass`, and folder structure is `bin/com/foo/bar/MyClass.class`, this is a case you need to have bin on your classpath.  Can you provide the relevant info in your question?

Comment: Could you please detail your folder structure? Do you really have two `bin` folders?

Comment: Hi I just updated. @Katona I have two bins because the second is a temporal project to evaluate. the first one.

Comment: Thanks a löt guys. It was a stupid mistake, I missed the last colon. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a semicolon (instead of a colon) to delimit the folders? I've never seen the use of the colon in classpath listing.

Comment: thanks, you hinted me into the solution. It was a colon but I was missing the last one.